# CSS incrementing transition animation on every button click

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Given

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {
    box.classList.add('move');
  } 
    
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.move {
    transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

with a JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rexhp29w/).

I want the box's x-position to increment by `20px` on every button click.

---

I am not sure how to proceed. I initially tried using `@KeyForms` but that requires the `from` and `to` prefixes, on which I cannot (I think) add a variable value. Same issue arises here, it seems I cannot have a variable in the css code which I can increment. Am I using the correct function at all (`transition`) ?

I also tried

```
if(event.target.id === "button") {
    if(!box.classList.contains('open')){
        box.classList.add('open');
    }else {
        box.classList.remove('open');
    }
  }
```

but that seems to move the box back and forth repetitively.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas? (I am adding the Javascript tag, since I suspect this problem may potentially be solved in JS directly).

Comment: Playing with `animate` in JS is funny :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the `x` position in a variable, increment by 20 every click and apply it to the `transform` style property:

```js
var x = 0, box = document.querySelector('.box');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  x += 20, box.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px)`;
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about that !

Answer (score 3):

Just keep on adding Using javascript style

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#button');

button.onclick = function () {
          document.querySelector('.box').style.transform += "translateX(20px)";
    };
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript style would answer your question. There is CSS style for javascript like `box.style.transform = 'translateX(20px)'`. In Javascript you can calculate styles values(Of course in CSS changing values with calculating is possible). So I added some codes like below.

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.box');
let cnt = 0;
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {
  console.log(box.style.transform)
    cnt++;
    console.log(cnt)
    box.style.transform = `translateX(${20 * cnt}px)`;
  } 
    
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.move {
    transform: translateX(20px);
}

.move1 {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```